# Unable to update collection

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

Hi Im trying to make an app that reads, writes, deletes and updates a database, im using mongoDB for the database, When i try and update the data Im getting undefined in the console, its meant to be getting the _id from the url and updating the data with using that, the app deletes and adds no problem. im really puzzled here so any help would be appreciated.

Server.js

```
   // Connection for the database
    enter code here const myConnectionString = 'mongodb+srv://<Name>: 
    <Password>cluster0.wvvof.mongodb.net/MusicDB?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
     mongoose.connect(myConnectionString, { useNewUrlParser: true });

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//what type of data im going to store
const MusicSchema = new Schema({
    Album: String,
    Band: String,
    Cover: String
});

const MusicModel = mongoose.model("musics", MusicSchema);

//sending json data
app.get('/api/albums', (req, res) => {
    MusicModel.find((err, data) => {
        res.json(data);
    });

});

// show album by id
app.get('/api/albums/:id', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params.id);

    MusicModel.findById(req.params.id, (err, data) => {
        res.json(data);
    });
})

// deleting by id
app.delete('/api/albums/:id', (req, res) => {
    console.log("delete Album:" + req.params.id);

    MusicModel.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id, (err, data) => {
        res.send(data);
    })
})

// update function by id
app.put('/api/albums/:id', (req, res) => {
    console.log("update Album:" + req.params.id);
    console.log(req.body);
    MusicModel.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, {new:true},
        (err, data) => {
            res.send(data);
        })
})



// writes to the db
app.post('/api/albums', (req, res) => {
    console.log("Album Received");
    console.log(req.body.Album);
    console.log(req.body.Band);
    console.log(req.body.Cover);

    MusicModel.create({
        Album: req.body.Album,
        Band: req.body.Band,
        Cover: req.body.Cover
    });
    res.send('Album added');

})
```

update.js

```
export class Update extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
        this.onChangeAlbum = this.onChangeAlbum.bind(this);
        this.onChangeBand = this.onChangeBand.bind(this);
        this.onChangeCover = this.onChangeCover.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            Band: "",
            Album: "",
            Cover: ""
        }
    }

    // get the album by id and update the state 
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("Load " + this.props.match.params.id);

        axios.get('http://localhost:4000/api/albums/' + this.props.match.params.id)
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({
                    Album: response.data.Album,
                    Band: response.data.Band,
                    Cover: response.data.Cover,
                    _id: response.data.id
                });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

    onChangeAlbum(r) {
        this.setState({
            Album: r.target.value
        });
    }
    onChangeBand(r) {
        this.setState({
            Band: r.target.value
        });
    }
    onChangeCover(r) {
        this.setState({
            Cover: r.target.value
        });
    }
    //only submit once
    onSubmit(r) {
        r.preventDefault();
        alert('btn clicked ' + ' ' + this.state.Album + ' ' + this.state.Band + ' ' + this.state.Cover);

        const UpdateAlbum = {
            Album: this.state.Album,
            Band: this.state.Band,
            Cover: this.state.Cover,
            _id: this.state.id
        };
        // making post req to server 
        axios.put('http://localhost:4000/api/albums/' + this.state._id, UpdateAlbum)
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res.data)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App" style={{ margin: '10%', fontSize: '30px' }}>
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Edit Album:</label>
                        <input type="text"
                            className="form-control"
                            value={this.state.Album}
                            onChange={this.onChangeAlbum}>
                        </input>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Edit Band:</label>
                        <input type="text"
                            className="form-control"
                            value={this.state.Band}
                            onChange={this.onChangeBand}>
                        </input>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Edit Cover Art:</label>
                        <textarea type="text"
                            className="form-control"
                            value={this.state.Cover}
                            onChange={this.onChangeCover}>
                        </textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input type="submit"
                            value="Edit Album"
                            className="btn btn-info">
                        </input>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>

        );
    }
}
```

Show.js

```
export class Show extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.ReloadData = this.ReloadData.bind(this);

    }

    state = {
        music: []

    }

    ReloadData() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:4000/api/albums')
            .then((response) => {
                this.setState({ music: response.data })
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }


    // when this componet is visable this method gets exe
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:4000/api/albums')
            .then((response) => {
                this.setState({ music: response.data })
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
    //passing data and a method down to albums
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <Albums myalbums={this.state.music} ReloadData={this.ReloadData}></Albums>

            </div>

        );
    }
}
```

AlbumItem.js

```
export class AlbumItem extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.DeleteAlbum = this.DeleteAlbum.bind(this);
    }

    //this function uses axios to go to the url below and gets the movie by the id and deletes it  then the reload data method is called 
    DeleteAlbum(r) {
        r.preventDefault();

        axios.delete('http://localhost:4000/api/albums/' + this.props.music._id)
            .then(() => {
                this.props.ReloadData();
            })
            .catch()
    }


    render() {
        return (

            <div style={{ margin: '.5% 20% 2.5% 20% ' }} >
                <Card style={{ textAlign: 'center', backgroundColor: '#a9f3d1' }}>

                    <Card.Body>
                        <Card.Title style={{ fontSize: '50px' }}>{this.props.music.Band}</Card.Title>
                        <Card.Text>
                            <Image alt="imgtext" src={this.props.music.Cover} width="500" height="400" thumbnail></Image>
                        </Card.Text>
                        <p style={{ fontSize: '40px' }}>{this.props.music.Album}</p>
                    </Card.Body>
                    <Button variant="danger" onClick={this.DeleteAlbum} style={{ fontSize: '25px' }} >Delete</Button>
                    <Link to={"/update/" + this.props.music._id} className="btn btn-info" style={{ fontSize: '25px' }}>Edit</Link>
                </Card>

            </div>

        );
    }
}
```

Album.js

```
export class Albums extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return this.props.myalbums.map((music) => {
            return <AlbumItem music={music} ReloadData={this.props.ReloadData}></AlbumItem>
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass data like this

```
DeleteAlbum(r) {
        r.preventDefault();

        axios.delete('http://localhost:4000/api/albums/', this.props.music._id)
            .then(() => {
                this.props.ReloadData();
            })
            .catch()
    }
```